# Parsing awkward CSV file with a dynamic number of columns gives error

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm a C# developer and this is my first attempt at writing F#.

I'm trying to read a Dashlane exported database in the CSV format. These files have no headers and a dynamic number of columns for each possible type of entry. The following file is an example of dummy data that I use to test my software. It only contains `password` entries and yet they have between 5 and 7 columns (I'll decide how to handle other types of data later) 
The first line of the exported file (in this case, but not always) is the email address that was used to create the dashlane account which makes this line only one column wide.

```
"accountCreation@email.fr"
"Nom0","siteweb0","Identifiant0","",""
"Nom1","siteweb1","identifiant1","email1@email.email","",""
"Nom2","siteweb2","email2@email.email","",""
"Nom3","siteweb3","Identifiant3","password3",""
"Nom4","siteweb4","Identifiant4","email4@email.email","password4",""
"Nom5","siteweb5","Identifiant5","email5@email.email","SecondIdentifiant5","password5",""
"Nom6","siteweb6","Identifiant6","email6@email.email","SecondIdentifiant6","password6","this is a single-line note"
"Nom7","siteweb7","Identifiant7","email7@email.email","SecondIdentifiant7","password7","this is a 
multi
line note"
"Nom8","siteweb8","Identifiant8","email8@email.email","SecondIdentifiant8","password8","single line note"
```

I'm trying to print the first column of each row to the console as a start

```
let rawCsv = CsvFile.Load("path\to\file.csv", ",", '"', false)       
for row in rawCsv.Rows do
    printfn "value %s" row.[0]
```

This code gives me the the following error on the `for` line

> Couldn't parse row 2 according to schema: Expected 1 columns, got 5

I haven't give the `CsvFile` any schema and I couldn't find on the internet how to specify a schema.

I would be able to remove the first line dynamically if I wanted to but it wouldn't change anything since the other lines have different column counts too.

Is there any way to parse this awakward CSV file in F# ?

Note: For each `password` row, only the column right before the last one matters to me (the password column)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that CSV file of as irregular structure as yours is a good candidate for processing with [CSV Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) or [CSV Parser](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html).

At the same time it does not seem difficult to parse this file to your likes with few lines of custom logic. The following snippet:

```
open System
open System.IO

File.ReadAllLines("Sample.csv") // Get data
|> Array.filter(fun x -> x.StartsWith("\"Nom")) // Only lines starting with "Nom may contain password
|> Array.map (fun x -> x.Split(',') |> Array.map (fun x -> x.[1..(x.Length-2)])) // Split each line into "cells"
|> Array.filter(fun x -> x.[x.Length-2] |> String.IsNullOrEmpty |> not) // Take only those having non-empty cell before the last one
|> Array.map (fun x -> x.[0],x.[x.Length-2]) // show the line key and the password
```

after parsing your sample file produces

```
>
val it : (string * string) [] =
[|("Nom3", "password3"); ("Nom4", "password4"); ("Nom5", "password5");
("Nom6", "password6"); ("Nom7", "password7"); ("Nom8", "password8")|]
>
```

It may be a good starting point for further improving the parsing logic to perfection.

Comment: I agree that prasing logic might be required, which is why I actually wrote the library in C# (which I am far more comportable than F#). I'll try to use your code to re-write my library in F#. I'll see how I can alter it so that it takes any data set (the `Name` field doesn't necessarily contain the `Name` string :-) Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I propose to read the csv file as a text file. I read the file line by line and form a list and then parse each line with CsvFile.Parse. But the problem is that the elements are found in Headers and not in Rows which is of type string [] option

```
 open  FSharp.Data
 open System.IO

 let readLines (filePath:string) = seq {
     use sr = new StreamReader(filePath)
     while not sr.EndOfStream do
         yield sr.ReadLine ()
 }

 [<EntryPoint>]
 let main argv = 
     let lines = readLines "c:\path_to_file\example.csv"
     let rows = List.map (fun str -> CsvFile.Parse(str)) (Seq.toList lines)
     for row in List.toArray(rows) do
         printfn "New Line"
         if row.Headers.IsSome then 
             for r in row.Headers.Value do
                 printfn "value %s" (r)
     printfn "%A" argv
     0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: There are no headers in my CSV file. Would this code still work ? I don't understand how `row.Headers` could have a value when there are none ...

Comment: also, I ended up re-writing the program in C#, parsing the file myself by reading it char by char ... but I'm still interrested in the F# solution.